# Stacey CMS Templates and Getting at Image assets in children

Tags: content-management-system, twig

I'm working with stacey (https://github.com/kolber/stacey)--the no frills, no database portfolio cms. Does anyone know why the following template code doesn't work in my default.html template? I know that the image won't show up this way, but I can't even get an image name to to show up in my default page.

```
{% for child in page.root %}
{% if child.children %}

{% for child in child.children %}
<div class="item">
{{ child.title }} - {{ child.type }}

{% for image in child.image %}
{{ image.name }}
{% endfor %}
</div>

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

image.name returns nothing to the template right now.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a very simple problem. The array for assets (like images) in child or page (depending on the context) is plural. The above code should read:

```
{% for image in child.images %}
```

That's it!